# Constructing Branch Cuts for $\sqrt{z}$ Not on the Negative Real Axis

Tags: branch-cuts

Can someone provide an example of different branch cut for the complex square root functioning than the classic one along the negative real axis? I'm a little hazy on the full purpose of branch cuts, is it to ensure a continuous domain is sent to a continuous range? So if we made a cut on the positive real axis, would we have to change out domain?

Comment: Any simple curve starting from (0,0) and going to infinity would do.

Comment: But is that the point? To send continuous domains to continuous ranges?

Comment: ??? The point of what? With respect to what?